# MongoDB E11000 duplicate key error with _idi_

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Trying to create new record at mongoose and getting:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: admin.inventoryitems index: _id_ dup key: { : ObjectId('5bdf1c4a60ec674ee1a10006') }
```

How I create item:

```
const createdItem = await InventoryItem.create(item);
```

item doesn't contain an '_id' field

Comment: Can you share your InventoryItem model definition and how `item` gets populated?

Answer (score -1):

Check in model there's no unique:true, value. This will always take unique data if not then throws mongo db duplicate value error.